# Where should you put the git hub workflow directory for actions in a full-stack project?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am building a full-stack react project with a node backend and would like to implement a git hub actions to automate pull requests for continuous integration. Currently, in my root directory, I have my project split into two directories a front-end directory holding the client-side application and a back-end directory container the serverside. My question is where should I place the .github directory and associated .workflow directory in the project? At the root level or in either the client-side or server-side directories?

[image]

Answer (score 22):

From [Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#about-yaml-syntax-for-workflows):

> You must store workflows in the .github/workflows directory in the root of your repository.

(workflow file cannot be inside subdirectory, it must be in `.github/workflows`)

You can define a naming convention for your repository: To keep the same logic that you were trying to implement with the subfolders, you could have `.github/workflows/economic_growth.back-end.yaml` and `.github/workflows/economic_growth.front-end.yaml`.